# What does "bumped into" convey in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, spoken-english

I found the following sentence in a book about learning English:

> My car slid and bumped into a parked station wagon.

According to the book, "bumped into" conveys that the car hit the station wagon "*slowly*". Is that correct? If not, what would you say to mean that your car hit another car slowly such that nothing serious happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's correct; "**bumped into**" implies the car was moving slowly when the accident happened, and often minimal damages occur, if any.

If you want to convey a more violent collision, you might use "**crashed into**" or "**slammed into**".